# Snippets for Bash Command Line?

Tags: bash, command-line, code-snippets, snipmate

I use vim and snipmate a lot for my python programming.  It would be ideal if I could have a snippet system for the bash command line.  Right now I use the gnome terminal in ubuntu...

For instance, if I type:

```
for<TAB>
```

I get:

```
for i in {1..50}; do SOMETHING; done
```

My google foo fails me, so once again I'm turning to SO.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware of some sort of "plugin" for this, but you could hack the completion scripts if you really wanted to.

Comment: pet - https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/pet-command-line-snippet-manager-linux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool that let you expand macros, you can use [autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/).

Answer (score 7):

There are several implementations:

[Boom](https://github.com/holman/boom)

[Bang](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/bang)

[Sheet](https://github.com/oscardelben/sheet)

Answer (score 1):

There is [Komandi](https://komandi.app), a multiplatform command snippets manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into marker for both bash and zsh which features

- search
- placeholders
- easy saving

Can be found at https://github.com/pindexis/marker